# Addon for Risk with cards

Tags: risk, board-game-adaptations

I remember download a file in the emule some 15 years ago, with a lot of cards that works as an addon for Risk. For e.g., one card give you terrorism so you can attack from Irak to some region in US, or sattelite, so you can jump a region to attack another one.

Some one knows anything about it? Name, location to download, or anything?
Some similar addons will be value also.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you had a look here:  (Files section)http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/181/risk

Comment: Well I didn't think it because (sorry for the elipsis) the addon was a very handwork, it was not for selling. But the link can help me to find another ones, thanks

Comment: I know of Risk AD 2210 that uses cards like invade from moon that lets you invade earth from the moon etc. Maybe it's some early variant of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Cardboard Republic](http://www.cardboardrepublic.com/articles/variants/variant-risk) I found a print and play version of an out of print unofficial expansion with action cards called [One World Dominion](http://www.cardboardrepublic.com/docs/OneWorldDominion.pdf).

Though it does not have the exact cards you describe, it seems to fit the bill.

Comment: is really really near to that addon, pretty similar